# How to add a field on NetSuite which is a dropdown down selection sourced from a saved search?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I need to add a field onto a contact page which is a drop-down field of addresses to select from for that contact.

I have created the saved search, which returns the required addresses, and I know you can create a drop-down field using a list. How do I merge these concepts and make the drop-down field with the result of the saved search.

PS: I would prefer to not write a suitescript with this, however if that is the only possible way I do know it is possible through this method.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this for summarize searches but to create a drop-down only with your search result as far as I know is not doable .

From a dev point of view I would Create a user even script onBeforeLoad or a client script on page unit to populate this field with select options coming In from your saved search .

Καλή τύχη